# insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext: only works after initializing NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7.1

I'm using Xcode 5 and iOS SDK 7.1.

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `NSFetchedResultsController`, which is copied from Apple's "Master-Detail Application" template. Everything is working fine within the `UITableViewController`. I have another view controller with the same context that inserts new managed objects into the `UITableViewController`'s table. Everything works fine if I load the `UITableViewController` at least once before I insert an object through the other view controller, but if I insert an object **before** I load the `UITableViewController` it is somehow lost. I'm inserting the object like so: (I created MyEntity using "Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass")

```
MyEntity *myEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

myEntity.field1 = value1;
myEntity.field2 = value2;

if (![context save:error])
    return nil;
```

and the save returns successfully, but for some reason the object I inserted is lost forever! I've been googling for something similar but didn't find anything. After conducting some research on the behavior I found out that it is enough to initialize the `NSFetchedResultsController` like so: (copied from Apple's template)

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"MyEntities"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

and keep a reference to it. As long as there's a reference to an initialized `NSFetchedResultsController`, I can insert objects and they get inserted.

Unless I'm missing something basic here, this is puzzling behavior!

Please help me..

Comment: If you are using an `NSSQLiteStoreType` persistent store, are you familiar with using Terminal to review the contents of your database? By checking your SQLite store, you can check whether the data has actually persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use Table View Controller and Core Data, it is always recommended to use Fetched Results Controllers, they will make development so much easier.

Fetched results controllers work in the same way as table views. Both have sections and rows. A fetched results controller can read managed objects from a managed object context and separate them into sections and rows. Each section is a group (if you specify it), and each row in a section is a managed object. You can then easily map this data to a table view and display it to the user.

After a fetched results controller is created on a managed object context, any change (insertion, deletion, modification, etc.) will immediately be reflected on the fetched results controller as well. For instance, you could create your fetched results controller to read the managed objects of the Person entity. Then in some other place in your application, you might insert a new MyEntity managed object into the context (the same context the fetched results controller was created on). Immediately, the new managed object will become available in the fetched results controller. This is just magical!

Fetched results controllers are exactly like table views in the sense that they have sections and rows, as explained before. You can use a fetched results controller to present managed objects in the GUI of your application with table views with ease.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However, you did not answer my question, I described a problem I'm having and you did not address it.. I advise you to reread the question.

Comment: Are you sure the object you are inserting is lost? Did you actually check it? Maybe in the way you linked the table view with the core data objects you missed some details. If the inserted object is not showing in the table view it does not mean it disappeared, maybe it is there, but you do not use it.

Comment: When inserting, before saving the context, did you check myEntity for nil? Inside the if (![context save:error]) { /**/ } also check if there is any error. If not, it means the objects is saved inserted successfully.

Comment: My advice is to create a new Empty Project with Core Data and reuse the generated code, it may solve your problem as it does not contain a NSFetchedResultsController object.